# beautiful soup python - put names together / find - find all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble with beautiful soup. started today to learn about it but can't manage to find a way to fix my issue.

I want to get only 1 link each time, and what is written in the h1 and p.

```
article_name_list = soup.find(class_='turbolink_scroller')
#find all links in the div
article_name_list_items = article_name_list.find_all('article')

#loop to print all out
for article_name in article_name_list_items:
    names = article_name.find('h1')    
    color = article_name.find('p')
    print(names)
    print(color)
```

the output is:

```
<h1><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/gw1diqgyr/km21a8hnc">Gonz Logo Coaches Jacket </a></h1>
<p><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/gw1diqgyr/km21a8hnc">Red</a></p>
```

I would like to get in output :
href="blablabla" 
Gonz Logo Coatches Jacket Red

and put it in a variable each time (if possible) like link = href"blablabla" and name = "gonz logo ..." or 3 variables with the color in another one.

EDIT here is how the page looks like:

```
<div class="turbolink_scroller" id="container" style="opacity: 1;">
  <article>
    <div class="inner-article">
      <a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/jackets/h21snm5ld/jick90fel">
    <img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/146917/vi/MCHFhUqvN0w.jpg" alt="Mchfhuqvn0w">
    <div class="sold_out_tag" style="">sold out</div>
  </a>
      <h1><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/h21snm5ld/jick90fel">NY Tapestry Denim Chore Coat</a></h1>
      <p><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/h21snm5ld/jick90fel">Maroon</a></p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>

</div>
```

EDIT 2: problem resolved (thank you)

here is the solution for others:

```
article_name_list = soup.find(class_='turbolink_scroller')
#find all links in the div
article_name_list_items = article_name_list.find_all('article')

#loop to print all out
for article_name in article_name_list_items:
    link = article_name.find('h1').find('a').get('href')
    names = article_name.find('h1').find('a').get_text()
    color = article_name.find('p').find('a').get_text()

    print(names)
    print(color)
    print(link)
```

thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're looking to put each of those into individual lists.

```
name_list = []
link_list = []
color_list = []
for article_name in article_name_list_items:
    names = article_name.find('h1').find('a', class_ = 'name-link').get_text()    
    links = article_name.find('p').find('a', class_ = 'name-link').get('href')
    colors = article_name.find('p').find('a', class_ = 'name-link').get_text()

    name_list.append(names)
    link_list.append(links)
    color_list.append(colors)
```

Not exactly sure what `article_name_list_items` looks like but `names` will get you the text of the `<h1>` element, `links` will get you the `href` of the `<p>` element, and `colors` will get you the text of `<p>` element.

You could also opt to include all elements in a list of lists which would be this (initialize new list `list_of_all` and replace 3 list appends with the single append in the second line):

```
list_of_all = []
list_of_all.append([names, links, colors])
```

Comment: i added the source page. thank you for the reply I am going to try what you wrote.
i'm not trying to do a list, i'm trying to create something structural then export to CSV to find the article i want

Comment: You can create the list of lists then put that into a dataframe and use `to_csv` to export into a CSV file.

Comment: hum didn't know about that technique i'm going to google it and try to find out! thanks a lot. You guys figured out my problem. didn't know I could go down the tree like that. it's going to help me in my project!

Comment: No problem. If you put it into Pandas, it's very easy to export in any format you want.

Comment: One last question very fast, now that I have everything is well arranged, is it possible with soup (or something else), to find one article precisely by imputing a keyword? 
for exemple: I want to find the "gonz logo jacket", is it possible someway to write "gonz logo" and it will find me that item? (of course I already parse all the articles before like in the question)

Comment: You can use [filter](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) if you want the list of items that contain what you're looking for. `list(filter(lambda x: x == 'gonz logo', your_list_of_names))`. That will filter the list of items for the condition you're looking for. If you're looking for the index value of the value you want, you can do `your_list_of_names.find('gonz logo')`

Comment: ^the second method only works with exact matches however.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are very close. However, you should tell us a little more about the structure of the page. Are all `article`s structured in the same h1>a,p>a structure?

Assuming this structure then the following should work:

```
names = article_name.find('h1').find('a').get('href')    
color = article_name.find('p').find('a').get_text()
```

Comment: i added the source page. i'm going to try what you wrote thanks